# Xamarin : Subscribing to multiple messages with same action

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have four view models M1, M2, M3, M4 from where I am sending a message to another view model M5. M5 performs same action when it receives a message from any of them. Currently, I have written code in M5 like this:

```
MessgingCenter.Subscribe<M1, string>(this, "abc", () => { DoSomething(); });
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<M2, string>(this, "abc", () => { DoSomething(); });
MessgingCenter.Subscribe<M3, string>(this, "abc", () => { DoSomething(); });
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<M4, string>(this, "abc", () => { DoSomething(); });
```

Can I achieve this in single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **hugo**'s method is preferred but if nothing else fits, you can also simply make the subscriber into a `string`. You just need to be careful doing it this way because it is easy for multiple subscribers to start getting triggered from the same send.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this , "abc", somethingString  => { DoSomething(somethingString); });
```

Then...

```
MessagingCenter.Send("something", "abc");
```

Edit: Adding interface code example mentioned in hugo's answer:

```
public interface IDoSomething { } //Does not necessarily have to have anything in it

public class ViewModelA : IDoSomething { }

public class ViewModelB : IDoSomething { }

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IDoSomething, string>(this, "abc", () => { DoSomething(); }); //IDoSomething works the same as deriving from a base class in this instance
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as this suits my problem better. The view models I have don't make a strong case to be inherited from same parent. But I upvoted his as well as that would suit most people.

Comment: @CuriousNewbie You can also, as hugo suggests, create an interface that each ViewModel implements. See edit for an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit M1, M2, M3, M4 from the same parent ViewModel (or interface) with a name such as "BaseViewModel" and then write:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BaseViewModel, string>(this, "abc", () => { DoSomething(); });
```